# How to easily convert seconds to a timestamp (HH:MM:SS) in MDX

Tags: date, timestamp, mdx, olap

What is a way to easily convert seconds to a timestamp (HH:MM:SS) in MDX?  I'd also like to look into providing days in that as well.  I was going to go through and use a bunch of calculated members as the values and then format them all into one string, but it seems like there has to be a better and cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just divide the seconds by 3600 * 24 so you have days, and then use a format string like this:

```
with member measures.duration as seconds / (3600.0 * 24.0)
           ,format_string = 'hh:mm:ss'
```

If you have durations of more than one day, then this can get a bit tricky, but you can find a solution here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2008/09/26/displaying-duration-values-mdx-expressions-in-format-string.aspx

Answer (score 0):

here is an example to do it:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[TimSpent (HH:MM:SS)] AS '[Measures].[Timespent]/ 86400', FORMAT_STRING = "hh:mm:ss"

SELECT [Assignment].[Element].[Element] ON ROWS, {[Measures].[Timespent], [Measures].[TimSpent (HH:MM:SS)]} ON COLUMNS

FROM [Activity]
```